# Cloud Run egress network high latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I have an issue with a Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Endpoint.
I have a small API backed by a Cloud Function requesting some data in a Cloud SQL instance. This part is very fast.

This API is exposed via Cloud Endpoints and an ESP proxy running (as in Google Cloud Platform documentation).

When launching, the latency is reasonable (around 200ms) but after sometimes (without any intervention) , latency is rising up around 2s. Then, if I force to redeploy the Cloud Run instance latency is returning to normal.

I have another endpoint with the exact same config but with a Cloud Function backed by another Cloud SQL instance and I don't have this problem.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks!

Antoine

Edit :

A trace with low latency:

[image: A trace with low latency]

Another with high latency:
[image]

Both are the exact same infrastructure. A restart of the Cloud Run ESP Proxy permits to reduce the latency for a while (6 hours the last time, this time it has been 24 hours without high latencies).

Comment: Are you using the [**API management**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/adding-api-management)? If yes, removing it should resolve the latency issue - *see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585413/google-cloud-endpoints-slower) post for more information*.




You might find this [**article**](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-reduce-latency-of-your-google-cloud-endpoints-apis-5bbe66385e32) useful for **reducing the latency** of your Google Cloud Endpoints APIs.

Comment: Hi Denis, thank you for your response. I'm not a specialist of Cloud Endpoints and I don't think I understand fully the processus. I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) to deploy the API endpoint (a cloud endpoint definition and an ESP proxy running on Cloud Run). I updated the question with screenshot of two traces with latencies.

Comment: You can check the latency of your own application (Cloud Functions) by directly applying [logging](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) and checking for any particular latencies on your app. Do you see any particular issue on the [Endpoint request logs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#track_api)? Are both Cloud Functions (same code, same runtime) and Cloud SQL instances (same Database version, machine type, storage capacity, etc.) alike?

Comment: Hi, I already checked the cloud function. Every call take less than 100ms to complete. The issue comes from Endpoint service / Cloud Run ESP. I checked the endpoint request logs and I saw no errors. The request latency passes from 259ms to 2,4s with no reason and then stayed around 2s. If I restart the ESP Proxy on Cloud run, latency is going back to 200ms.

Comment: Where the Cloud Run ESPs created in different zones?

Comment: Nope, always the same instance in the same zone (I taint the TF ressource and then apply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update :
Updating the ESP proxy to v2 (gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2) seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the CheckServiceControl latency?

ESP has local cache for ServiceControl call.  Cache expired in 5 minutes. The low latency maybe from the cache hit and the high latency maybe from the cache miss.

Comment: I don't think so because I have a call every minute in 6 locations, and I had more than 4 days with low latency. Then latency is raising without any apparent reason and stays high until I restart the ESP Proxy Cloud Run. As you can see on the two screenshots, high latency comes from the CheckServiceControl (from 10ms to 1s) but also from a delay to the cloud function call (backend raising from 36ms to 1,2 sec whereas cloud function latency stays low around 30 ms)

Comment: I see, you are suspecting that Cloud Run egress network may have latency issue. After certain period of time,  the latency will increase, re-start the Cloud Run service will fix it.   If so, can you file this issue to Google Cloud Run team?  Your issue title is misleading, could you change it to Cloud Run egress network high latency

Comment: Thank you for your time. I edited the title and opened an issue with the cloud run team as you suggested. I will keep you posted here, if they find the issue.